# Typescript Generics : why does this[Key] type sometimes get inferred, sometimes not

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics, stackblitz

I'm stumbling on an inference problem within a generic class & with a generic method.
Here is my code.

```
export class MyClass<T> {
  name: string;
  array: Array<T>;

  constructor() {
    const a = this.test('name');                      // a: this["name"]       NOK
    const b = this.test('name') ?? '';                // b: this["name"] | ""  NOK
    const c = this.test('array') ?? ([] as Array<T>); // c: T[]                OK
    const d = this.test('array');                     // d: this["array"]      NOK
  }

  public test<K extends keyof this>(name: K): this[K] {
    return this[name];
  }
}
```

Notice how `c`, got inferred correctly aka (`T[]`) but all other cases are returning as `this['myProperty']`.

[The stackblitz for demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tzjj8r)

Also this is not reproductible on the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4&ssl=6&ssc=24&pln=5&pc=1#code/PTAEEkFsAcHsCcAuoDOiCeAbApigFttoigLABQAljAsgOQB0waW29AxiirQNznnYAPOElBtMAQ06gAsugDCEzgB4AKgD5QAb3KhQAO3GRsALlSJ4FPQHNQAXlC0eO0OPjxx6UwEE3H1RvsAbQBdXjJnNlg9NHgAVzZEBAAKAEotZ11I6ORxO1BEPAoUekRcRCTaAyNaFO5QEBdTAqLAgCIq7FbgjNEotFAAIzzm4tK0Co6a0AB%20aYceerARto6u0AAfUFbWnqz%20tmHC0bKK13d0KdnQJJCXFFAfc-9axdFTFRDdvuQAE0OikonWhnDw1OoNH5NI5tEHoLrOAC%20fDIumgsQGmAoBzGiCUAGlQIJSnofvcANbYdCwABm%20SOaiSHVMeJSUJaeOC6RRulA8CIsXgejpLQ6oUR5CRZCAA).

Comment: Are you sure you actually have a problem? If I open up either of those links and start typing e.g. `a.repeat(3)` or `d.push` in the constructor I get autocompletion and no type errors, although the tooltip is admittedly not super helpful.

Comment: In your example, `this["name"]` resolves to `string` (and in the case of `b`, `""` is a subtype of `string` so it's expected that it should be `this["name"]`), and `this["array"]` resolves to `T[]`. Are you just annoyed by the IntelliSense names? It seems like there are no type problems.

Comment: After digging more, it seems like this is a problem related to StackBlitz.

Comment: Actually what I'm the most annoyed with is that the type `this[myProp]` isn't resolved or inferred to the reel type. Making the typing a bit useless while write/maintaining the code.